# How to remove the key from the result of FOR JSON PATH in SQL 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

We have begun to use FOR JSON PATH with in our SQL code for many different reasons. In this scenario though I'm having a little bit of issues with it. I am trying to get a list of OrderItemIds into a single JSON string. But what it produces is an array of objects with a single Property -> {"OrderItemId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}. My goal is to produce a json string with just the values of the Guids and not their key.

```
SELECT 
    OrderItemId 
FROM 
    OrderItems 
FOR JSON PATH
```

Expected:

```
"["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"]"
```

Actual:

```
"[{"OrderItemId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"OrderItemId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}]"
```

Attempt 1: (Successful, but only in part)

```
CONCAT(
    '[',
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ',"'+ST1.[value]+'"'  AS [text()]
            FROM @table ST1            
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 9999),
    ']')
```

Results: So this little bit of code works exactly how I would want my result to work. This is using FOR XML PATH instead of JSON PATH, which is fine of course because it produces what I want. But this bit of code is kind of daunting to toss and use all over the place where I want it. So we thought why not stick it into a function and we can pass the values to it.

Attempt 2: (AGAIN successful, but only in part) Make a custom type and function

```
CREATE TYPE ValueList
AS TABLE ([value] [nvarchar](100) NULL)

CREATE FUNCTION ConvertToValueList(@table ValueList READONLY)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
AS BEGIN
RETURN CONCAT(
            '[',
            SUBSTRING(
                (
                    SELECT ',"'+ST1.[value]+'"'  AS [text()]
                    FROM @table ST1            
                    FOR XML PATH ('')
                ), 2, 9999),
            ']')
```

Usage example:

```
DECLARE 
    @OrderItemIds ValueList;

INSERT INTO @OrderItemIds 
(
    [value]
)
SELECT 
    [OrderItemId] 
FROM 
    [dbo].[OrderItems]

SELECT [dbo].[ConvertToValueList](@OrderItemIds)
```

Results:
    This ends up working exactly as planned. The issue I run into now is when I am wanting to use that function in a View. I can't because I need to declare the value list in order to pass into the function.

End Note:
    So for now I am just using the Concat statement from attempt 1 until we can come up with a better solution.

Comment: Try this approch https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672860/764369

Answer (score 0):

with XML PATH:

```
DECLARE @OrderItems TABLE (OrderItemId UniqueIdentifier PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @OrderItems 
    VALUES ( NEWID () )
         , ( NEWID () )
         , ( NEWID () )
         , ( NEWID () )
         , ( NEWID () )

SELECT   CONCAT (STUFF ( (  SELECT  ',' +QUOTENAME (CONVERT (VARCHAR(36), OrderItemId ),'"')
                            FROM    @OrderItems 
                            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE 
                         ). value('text()[1]','varchar(max)')
                       , 1, 1, '"['
                       )
                ,']"'
                )
;
```

Result:

```
"["135B908B-E5FD-4658-B69C-4E380509581B","4EEDF234-167D-4141-8542-A0173482BFD6","53901E4C-0486-44D5-A0AB-C6BC2FAE39B1","A263D28A-0948-461D-BC46-F9A6D167E37F","5795D046-098E-4AFB-9B2C-FB3DC56F6F31"]"
```

Comment: If you can see in my examples this one of solutions we've tried. We just created our own type and made a function. I basically want that to be reusable inside of a view.